# Upgrading Cassandra 1.2.9 to 2.0.x

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade a single-node Cassandra cluster from 1.1.5 to 2.0.x.

My production server is running on Linux. I pulled the data folder to my Windows box, keeping the `system` keyspace, along with a particular one I'm interested in, and dropping the rest after getting Cassandra up.

I upgraded and tested:

- 1.1.5 -> 1.2.0
- 1.2.0 -> 1.2.8
- 1.2.8 -> 1.2.9

Ran:

- `nodetool upgradesstables`
- `describe schema`
- `select * from table limit 100`

Everything looks good with 1.x versions.

When trying to upgrade to 2.0.7, I run into an issue (I saw the recommended upgrade path is 1.2.9 -> 2.0.7):

```
INFO 16:43:01,758 Opening C:\path\mykeyspace-mytable-ic-655 (97902117 bytes)
ERROR 16:43:12,443 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Incompatible SSTable found.  Current version jb is unable to read file: C:\path\mykeyspace\mytable\mykeyspace-mytable.mytable_location_idx-he-647.  Please run upgradesstables.
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:409)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:391)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.init(AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.java:52)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.addIndexedColumn(SecondaryIndexManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:277)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:415)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:386)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:309)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:266)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:290)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:480)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:569)
```

I *did* run upgradesstables from 1.2.9/bin, after starting 1.2.9/bin/cassandra. 
Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied in the fact that I had only partially migrated my production cluster to my local environment. I had copied the entire `system` keyspace files and only some of the `data` files for just one of my keyspaces.

I fixed the problem by redoing everything:

- set up 1.1.5 locally
- used cqlsh to connect to it, dropped all other keyspaces and tables I didn't have available locally
- migrated (not sure which ones did the trick, assume I did them all): 1.1.5 -> 1.2.0 -> 1.2.8 -> 1.2.9 -> 2.0.0 -> 2.0.1 -> 2.0.7.
- *possibly* deleted any mismatching index files Cassandra was complaining about when starting up (not sure if I encountered any when doing the last magically working upgrades, but this let me advance through versions during previous attempts). My guess is Cassandra looks at all of them, but `upgradesstables` occasionally leaves some behind.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you did this:
migrated (not sure which ones did the trick, assume I did them all): 1.1.5 -> 1.2.0 -> 1.2.8 -> 1.2.9 -> 2.0.0 -> 2.0.1 -> 2.0.7.

Comment: @JorgeCornejoBellido I started those versions of cassandra and let them finish starting up - they migrated the data to newer formats. possibly ran _upgradesstables_.

Comment: @Buffalo, I am sure you're aware of Apache Cassandra 4.0 release last summer and I would recommend you upgrade finally to 4.0.1+ version. For inspiration, see [4.0 overview here](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-4.0-Overview.html).

Answer (score 3):

`mytable_location_idx-he-647` is a `1.1.5` sstable (`he` is the version, `h` is 1.1 and `e` is the 5th version of `h`). Run upgradesstables again and verify all the sstables get migrated. the version of the sstable should start with an `i` for 1.2, and you want it to be at `ic` before upgrading to 2.0.