# Cassandra migration from 1.2.9 to 3.11

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

I need to migrate from Cassandra 1.2.9 to 3.11.

The plan is to go like this: 1.2.9-> 2.0.11 -> 2.2.* -> 3.11

Do you consider that is better to upgrade the cluster or to migrate data from 1.2.9 to 2.2 and after that to 3.11?

Is anything that you can consider a blocker?

I started from those threads:

- [Upgrading Cassandra 1.2.9 to 2.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581577/upgrading-cassandra-1-2-9-to-2-0-x)
- [upgrade apache cassandra from 2.0.11 to 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472169/upgrade-apache-cassandra-from-2-0-11-to-3-11)

Answer (score 0):

Migration will require additional hardware also you may not have continuous traffic going for you with migration. Do the upgrades as mentioned in upgrade guides/ instructions. You will do well going upgrade way.